# RFID reader device IP not seen in established state in netstat

Tags: c#, tcp, ip, netstat

I am trying to write a C# code, that will help me get the RFID reader device IP.

I am using netstat C# implementation which gives all the local and foreign addresses.
Now the problem is, after connection through Ethernet TCP/IP, I sometimes see in `netstat` that the reader IP is temporarily seen with `TIME_WAIT` state and then disappears.
Never seen it in established state with my PC and so my code cannot pick up that IP.

Also I've set my Marvell yukon LAN adapter to 10Mps full duplex rather than Auto mode.
So the big question is do I need to set/configure with the adapter or do I write another C# code that will detect my reader IP irrespective of the state of TCP/IP connection.

Note: Pinging the reader works all the time when connected.
I tried resetting LAN and the reader, but it still doesn't show up in `netstat` output.

EDIT: I am using the http://towardsnext.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/netstat-in-c/ for reference

Comment: Do you want to find out your machine's IP address or the reader's?

Comment: I still don't quite understand. You don't know the reader's address, but a ping works. But that sounds like you already know the address..? -- More ideas: Ever tried Wireshark? Your RFID reader app has to find the reader somehow as well, maybe Wireshark can help.

Comment: OK I'll give wire shark a try..Basically I cannot see the reader IP address in netstat (Although I know it so I )